# On change of input field in step 1 reset values in step 2 of mat stepper

Tags: angular, angular-material, stepper, angular-lifecycle-hooks

I am using Angular material stepper for my application. Each step has individual components.

**parent.html:**

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper [linear]="isLinear" #stepper>
  <mat-step >
  <app-child-1></app-child-1>
  </mat-step>

  <mat-step>
  <app-child-2></app-child-2>
  </mat-step>
  
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

**child-1**

```
<form [formGroup]="firstFormGroup">
      <ng-template matStepLabel>Fill out your name</ng-template>
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
        <input matInput placeholder="Last name, First name" formControlName="firstCtrl" required>
      </mat-form-field>
      <div>
        <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

**child-2**

```
<form [formGroup]="secondFormGroup">
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Address</mat-label>
        <input matInput formControlName="secondCtrl" 
               required>
      </mat-form-field>
      <div>
        <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
        <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

it works like when user enters name in step 1 ,the value of address in second form will be loaded from backend. In case if the user changes the name field again , the address field shld get reset. I can reset the stepper but it designed to be like stepper reset should not happen i should clear the field which is inside step 2. What is the possible way to do this. ? **is it possible to bind this field in child 1 component to any life cycle hooks of child 2 component.** Please guide me

Answer (score 0):

use [editable]="true" in mat-step tag

look first example code,

example: [enter link description here](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/examples)

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer

Comment: in parent when you previous to step 1 after entering name you get address and can pass into second component with @input. maybe ngOnChanges work

Comment: I tried the logic to reset the field on NgOnchanges in child component but is not working

Comment: But as you mentioned let me try in ngonchanges of step1 component..